# display:ruby not available on chrome

Tags: html, css, frontend

I just encountered this. I'm using display:ruby to completely put a line of text in a single line. In firefox, this code works perpectly but not in chrome or in safari.

I used display:ruby instead of display:inline-block because it doesnt do the job.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the docs of display: ruby - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Ruby has limited support, what are you trying to achieve?  If it is that you just want text to be on one line, why not use `white-space:nowrap;`?

Answer (score 15):

`display: ruby;` has limited compatibility. You can use `white-space: nowrap;` insted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispaly:flow-root;`
The element generates a block element box that establishes a new block formatting context, defining where the formatting root lies.